# Can I destroy Bennu, if I shoot it with my electron gun?

Tags: electrostatics, newtonian-gravity, electric-fields, accelerator-physics, asteroids

The asteroid Bennu seems to be just a pile of rubble weakly held together by gravitational forces. Newton’s law, -Gm<sub>1</sub>m<sub>2</sub>/r<sup>2</sup>, and Coulomb’s law, +k<sub>e</sub>q<sub>1</sub>q<sub>2</sub>/r<sup>2</sup>, have exactly the same form but opposite sign.   So if I add enough charge to the asteroid, it will simply fly apart!  The amount of charge needed is sqrt(G/k<sub>e</sub>) = 8.6 x 10<sup>-11</sup> Coulombs per kilogram.  Bennu is 78 billion kilograms, so it will take 6.7 Coulombs to destroy it. 
I happen to be floating nearby and I also happen to have a 5 MV, 100 mA electron gun in my pocket.  If I point it at the asteroid and shoot for a couple of minutes, will that do the trick? 
(I’m thinking this might work better if we fire protons at the asteroid and then electrons at high speed in the opposite direction so they don’t get in the way?)

[Edit #1] The mean radius of Bennu is 250 meters. This corresponds to a capacitance of 4$\pi\epsilon$<sub>0</sub>r = 28 picoFarads. The resulting voltage will 6.7 Coulombs / 28 picoFarads = 240 MV.  So I guess my 5 MV gun is not going to do it.  I need a bigger gun! 
[Edit #2] If I've done the calculation correctly, the energy needed to disassemble Bennu gravitationally is (3/2)GM<sup>2</sup>/r = 2.4*10^9 Joules (about 1000 pounds of TNT). That is similar to 240 MV * 100 mA * 100 seconds.
[Edit #3] Despite the similarity of the governing equations, it is practically impossible create a uniform bulk charge-density. The charge can only be injected into a thin layer on the surface and in any case will tend to migrate to the surface. The force on the surface particles will be something like 
 k<sub>e</sub>q(q.$\pi$r<sub>g</sub><sup>2</sup>/4$\pi$r<sub>b</sub><sup>2</sup>)/r<sub>b</sub><sup>2</sup>) instead of k<sub>e</sub>q(q.(4/3)$\pi$r<sub>g</sub><sup>3</sup>/(4/3)$\pi$r<sub>b</sub><sup>3</sup>)/r<sub>b</sub><sup>2</sup>) where r<sub>b</sub> is the radius of the asteroid and r<sub>g</sub> is the radius of a grain and q is the total charge on the asteroid. For small grains and a thin surface layer the former could be millions of times larger than the latter.  Even a small incidental net charge will cause all the surface dust to disappear. Maybe that's why Bennu looks like a rubble pile rather than the sand pile that NASA was hoping for?

Comment: Why do you think the asteroid will fly apart instead of the charged particles just flying off it?

Comment: @ G. Smith That's good point.  This would have to be done carefully (gradually?) otherwise the small particles or grains that detach might carry away a much larger fraction of charge than mass.

Comment: @ G. Smith I edited the question to add a calculation of the voltage required.  It seems like I'll need a much BIGGER gun!  I suppose another good sanity check would be to calculate how much gravitational energy it would take to disassemble the asteroid and compare this with the energy from the gun.

Comment: @ G. Smith I'm not sure I really answered your question. First, the electrons have to reach the asteroid. This requires the gun's voltage to be sufficiently higher than the asteroid's voltage. 
Second, the electrons must 'attach' to the asteroid's material. This means that either they remain relatively immobile in or on an insulating material (static electricity) or that they are held in a conducting material by the surface work function.

Comment: Why not use a bomb? Electrons have a mind of their own. You need brute force.

Comment: @ my2cts Yes, about 1000 lbs of TNT should do it. But I think you're forgetting, the destruction of Bennu is just to demonstrate the technology. After that we will scale up the electron gun massively and install it in a large spherical spacecraft. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_Star